# How can I use a local image as the base image with a dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I'm working on a dockerfile.
I just realised that I've been using `FROM` with indexed images all along.

So I wonder:

- How can I use one of my local (custom) images as my base (`FROM`) image without `pushing` it to the index?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

You can use it without doing anything special. If you have a local image called `blah` you can do `FROM blah`. If you do `FROM blah` in your Dockerfile, but *don't* have a local image called `blah`, *then* Docker will try to pull it from the registry.

In other words, if a Dockerfile does `FROM ubuntu`, but you have a local image called `ubuntu` different from the official one, your image will override it.

Comment: does not work for me - could be a problem with boot2docker? I have latest version 1.3.1  ...Docker does not appear to check locally first (or maybe does not report it) it goes straight to attempting to pull from registry  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27046118/202168

Comment: @Anentropic I'm using boot2docker 1.5. 
bash-4.3$ docker images
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu1504gcc484           latest              0378ea1c0b6c        19 hours ago        1.36 GB
And doing "FROM ubuntu1504gcc484" in my other Dockerfile, and this works just fine. (Apologies for the poor formatting)

Comment: I don't know any more, I'm also now on 1.5

Comment: I created an image and tagged it for our local registry.  Tagged that way, it doesn't find it with just the name, and the full name includes the registry so if you reference that way it will fetch the tag there.  You can tag it again with the simple form of the name and it will find it before looking to the registry.  Worked for me.

Comment: Minikube/Kubernetes issue - I had some trouble trying to figure this out because, in one terminal, `docker images` was showing the base image that I wanted to use but, in the other terminal, I had run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` and that puts you in sort of a "virtual environment" in which my base image didn't exist. I simply had to rebuild it here then I was good to go

Comment: No, this is incorrect. Docker is trying to pull an image from a remote registry despite the fact that I have an image with the same name locally, listed in `docker image list`.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional I think this would warrant opening a separate question asking why Docker does that, including how you're running the container (`docker run` or otherwise), the output of `docker image list` or `docker images`, and the exact version that you're running. If you do so, feel free to tag me and I'll be happy to take a look!

Comment: Remember to refer to the complete name of the image which is "<image_name>:<tag>". You can find the image name under the column heading "REPOSITORY" and the tag under the column heading "TAG" in the output of the command `docker image ls`

Comment: none of these works, docker keeps prepending docker.io/blabla to the image name

Comment: This works on Intel mac OS, not on M1 mac OS, in my tests.

Comment: I resolved it by @codeman48 answer. 
FROM image_name:tag

Comment: None of these worked for me, only way I got it to work was adding the `--pull=false` flag in the command I used to build so like this : `docker build . -t IMAGE_NAME --pull=false`

Comment: it doesn't work!

Answer (score 171):

For anyone who faces this issue in the future, where you have the image in your local but `docker build` still tries to pull the image from docker hub, the problem might be that the architecture types are different.

[image: Trying to pull from docker.io even though image exists]

You can check the architecture of the image using

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}' IMAGE_NAME
```

Now in your `Dockerfile` change `FROM IMAGE_NAME` to something like `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 IMAGE_NAME` and docker would now use the local image.

Comment: this is extremely relevant for Mac M1 these days. 1+

Comment: For macbook M1, this is exactly the case.

Comment: This isn't what I came looking for but it's damn handy to know! +1

Comment: Brilliant, nailed it.

Comment: it took me 1.5-2 hrs to find this solution with a "restart" 

Comment: For me even after providing platform, didn't work. Had to run the command with this param : 
``DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t <new-image-name> .``

referred from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74023547/3962816

Docker version : 20.10.7 , Mac M1 chip.

Comment: This was it for me! Embarrassingly not the first time it's caught me out

Comment: This ended my day-long nightmare. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 57):

Verified: it works well in Docker 1.7.0.

Don't specify `--pull=true` when running the `docker build` command

From this thread on [reference locally-built image using FROM at dockerfile](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14943):

> If you want use the local image as the base image, pass without the
> option `--pull=true`
> `--pull=true` will always attempt to pull a newer
> version of the image.

Comment: If your image have a `-` character (`my-image` for example) in name then your docker will not resolve this image locally, I don't know why, anyway to fix it simply not use `-` character, tested on docker-compose 1.8 and docker 1.11

Comment: I had no problem with a hyphenated name on `Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72`, but make sure if you tagged your image you include the tag as part of the image specification (FROM localimage:tag).

Comment: @deFreitas that seems to be true, I have an image with hyphens in the name and Docker is trying to pull it from a remote registry despite an image with that name existing locally. If this rule about hyphens in the name turned out to be true this would be pure madness.

Comment: @deFreitas: following my last comment, I tried with underscore intead of the hyphens and got the same issue, docker trying to pull the image from remote despite local image present. In my case at least the hyphens are not the problem.

Comment: Late to the game here, but anyone still experiencing this issue, make sure the images you are building from match the architecture you are building for. I was trying to use an arm64 local image to build for an amd64 target.

Make sure your local image architecture matches your build architecture.

Answer (score 18):

I had to disable `BUILDKIT` on a mac with M1 to be able to use a local image.
You can do it by setting the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` environment variable to 0.

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0  docker build -t YOUR_TAG --pull=false .`

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?  I updated to the latest version of Docker today and ran into this issue for the first time.  I had to disable BUILDKIT to make it work as well.

Comment: @raysn0w My guess is the new BUILDKIT defaults to using images built for the native platform, i.e. arm64 for M1. (This is why it is much faster) If your local image is not built for arm64, it cannot use it.

Comment: What If you're trying to build multiarch image with buildx though?

Answer (score 9):

You can have - characters in your images. Assume you have a local image (not a local registry) named centos-base-image with tag 7.3.1611.

```
docker version 
      Client:
       Version:         1.12.6
       API version:     1.24
       Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.el7.centos.x86_64
       Go version:      go1.7.4

      Server:
       Version:         1.12.6
       API version:     1.24
       Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.el7.centos.x86_64
       Go version:      go1.7.4

docker images
 REPOSITORY            TAG
 centos-base-image     7.3.1611
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos-base-image:7.3.1611
RUN yum -y install epel-release libaio bc flex
```

Result

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 315.9 MB
Step 1 : FROM centos-base-image:7.3.1611
  ---> c4d84e86782e
Step 2 : RUN yum -y install epel-release libaio bc flex
  ---> Running in 36d8abd0dad9
...
```

In the example above `FROM` is fetching your local image, you can provide additional instructions to fetch an image from your custom registry (e.g. `FROM localhost:5000/my-image:with.tag`). See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry and https://docs.docker.com/registry/#tldr

Finally, if your image is not being resolved when providing a name, try [adding a tag to the image when you create it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

[This GitHub thread describes a similar issue of not finding local images by name](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8975).

> By omitting a specific tag, docker will look for an image tagged "latest", so either create an image with the :latest tag, or change your FROM

Answer (score 7):

Remember to put not only the tag but also the repository in which that tag is, this way:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG                       IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
elixir                                    1.7-centos7_3             e15e6bf57262        20 hours ago        925MB
```

You should reference it this way:

```
elixir:1.7-centos7_3
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone with a MAC os m1 architecture I needed to add the `--platform=linux/amd64` parameter before the base image. Example

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 baseImage:tag
```

I found that that if you are using `docker-compose.yml`, you can move the platform parameter in the service section, a lot more clean:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
    test:
        platform: platform=linux/amd64
        image: baseImage
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! You've helped me immensely!

Answer (score 5):

On M1 mac I had to both specify image platform and name:tag

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 myimagename:2.0.0.a
```

i.e.

1. if docker build is with platform
   `docker build . --tag chrome-nodejs-java --platform=linux/amd64`,
   then platform should be specified after `FROM`
2. If you have image in `docker images` with specific name and tag (not tag `latest`), then you must specify that tag

Much simpler way may be just using IMAGE ID.

```
FROM c08a03a92df0
```

Anyways use `docker images` more often.
It does not list platforms of images.
For that use `docker inspect imagenameOrID`
or `docker inspect --format='{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}' imagenameOrID`

So in my case it did not worked for myimagename (as there was no `latest`, i.e. built without tag), but worked for myimagename:2.0.0.a

In other words, if `docker images` does not have your image with tag `latest`, then you cannot use `FROM` without specific version tag

---

Thanks to above highvoted answers by @jpetazzo, @Anuj Bansal and @SomeGuy.

Answer (score 3):

## For docker >= 23.0

Since Docker 23.0, `docker build` has become an alias for `docker buildx build`.

You might be using a custom [builder instance](https://docs.docker.com/build/builders/), set the builder instance to `default` with this command and run your build command again.

```bash
docker buildx use default
```

### More details

You can list your builder instances with this command:

```bash
docker buildx ls
```

You should see a wildcard next to the default builder.

```
NAME/NODE    DRIVER/ENDPOINT             STATUS  BUILDKIT             PLATFORMS
mybuilder    docker-container
  mybuilder0 unix:///var/run/docker.sock running v0.12.1              linux/arm64*, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
default *    docker
  default    default                     running v0.11.6+0a15675913b7 linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a dumb workaround but... if your image has the name `blah` and an id `b2d34289abae`, then you could change the `FROM` line in your docker file from

`FROM blah`

to

`FROM b2d34289abae`

You can get the image ids by doing `docker images`

I would just treat that as a temporary workaround however for like local testing or something along those lines.

Comment: This is actually clever, as this way we select very specific image build,
even when it has no name or tag.

Answer (score 1):

For users with M1 chips, problem can be arisen when platform differs of local image differs from target Dockerfile. In my case, I've built base image with M1 support and then tried to use command `FROM` in image that was building with platform `linux/amd64`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this on an M1 Mac with engine version 20.10.14. It wasn't obvious from `docker build --help`, but passing `--pull=false` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Our `/etc/docker/daemon.json` had a line declaring

```
"disable-legacy-registry" : true,
```

With that line in, the local registry was refusing access.
With it removed, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

For latest Docker versions that happens because you haven't pointed base image platform type so you should:

```
docker build --platform=${DESIRED_PLATFORM} -t ${TAG} .
```