# use image-file in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have to deliver an application running in several containers to a customer.
I can export all single images to files with:

```
docker save --output app1.tar app2
docker save --output app2.tar app2
...
```

My goal is do deliver a ZIP-folder with only the docker-compose.yml and the images (app1.tar,app2.tar...) needed to run the containers.

Is there any way to reference an image-file in the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Add the dockerfiles to your zip too and reference the image build from the right dockerfile in your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: but then i would have to deliver the complete source code with it?

Comment: True, if you don't want that you can .tar your images and put it in a zip with your docker-compose.yml. Provide it to someone who needs to unzip it and untar the image and just reference the image name in docker-compose? For me it seems to work like the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032392/docker-compose-doest-allow-to-use-local-images

Comment: but then you have to docker load every single image by hand or not?

Comment: You can script it to save all images in one .tar so you only need to untar that one (here all images are saved in one .tar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575674/how-to-save-all-docker-images-and-copy-to-another-machine)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you can't reference a tar ball from a docker-compose file.

You need to provide an addition script with the ZIP folder. This script would import the images, and start docker-compose. It can be more or less like below:

```
docker import app1.tar
docker import app2.tar
docker-compose up
```

Comment: I did `docker import`of both my containers. But, `docker-compose up` still trying to rebuild images. But I want just use imported. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: @AnisSmail Using `docker load < image.tar` instead of `docker import image.tar` will do the trick. You can confirm whether the image has been loaded with the correct tag by checking the output of `docker image ls`.

Comment: for SAVED images u should use `docker load --input image.tar`

Answer (score -4):

Try to export zip the plesk onyx docker.

Use this code:

```
<code>
FROM wpcache
MAINTAINER wpCache® support@wpcache.co

ENV WPCACHE_VERSION="2.0"

# download wpcache
RUN curl -O "https://github.com/wpCache/wpCache/raw/master/version/2.0.zip"

# unarchive wpcache
RUN unzip 2.0.zip
</code>
```

```
finde PATH PLESK  exoport  zip export per domain

how to make dir  main root   example:  domain.com /wpCache

docker export zip   /wpCache
```