# Reuse image built by one service in another service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have this project structure:

```
proj/
├── docker
│   └── myservice
│       └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  master:
      build: docker/myservice

  slave:
      image: proj_master
      depends_on: master
```

I want the `master` service to create an image, which will be used by the `master` and the `slave` services (with different parameters, not shown here). By trial and error I have found out that the slave must refer to the image `proj_master`.

- Where is this documented?
- Why do I need to make a reference to the `proj`? Usually a docker composer file is agnostic related to where it is located ...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Docker Compose builds your image with the name `proj_master`, beacuse you did not specify an image name under your `master` service in the Compose file.

You have a `build` section, so Docker Compose will build the image and give it a name based on your `<directory_name_where_you_run_compose>_<service_name>:latest`. I did not find this in the documentation, but tried with one of my projects, and it's in line with what you experienced.

You can fix your project by specifying the image name in your Compose file and using the same image for both services:

```
version: '3'


services:

  master:
      build: docker/myservice
      image: username/masterimage:version


  slave:
      image: username/masterimage:version
      depends_on: master
```

Comment: can we use **build** and **image** together ?!

Comment: @MahdiImani what do you mean together? We usually use `build` and `image` together under the same service. `build` tells docker how to build and `image` tells docker what the image name should be. They are sort of together :) What more are you trying to acieve?

Comment: tried this but it fails on pull as it tries to pull an nonexistent image

Comment: @dalore Exactly, on `docker-compose pull` it complains with *ERROR: manifest for image-name:tag not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown*, since no upstream/registry image of that name exists. This is why I am now rolling this back to use copy-pasted/WET configs, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63479416/11477374).

Answer (score 23):

This feature is called [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields).

You can just link your slaves to your master.

```
django_project: 
  &django_project
  image: python:3.7.6-alpine
   command: ....  

django_project_task1:
  <<: *django_project
  command: /start-task1.sh 

django_project_task2:
  <<: *django_project
  command: /start-task2.sh
```

Now the all share the same source but use different command to start.

Also, you have to understand one more thing.

Since Docker uses "layers" your Dockerfile is not going to be recompiled for every "sub-proccess" and volume size is going to be shrinked.

There is a perfect [article on this topic](https://medium.com/@kinghuang/docker-compose-anchors-aliases-extensions-a1e4105d70bd)

Also check out this article about [running multiple process in one container](https://ahmet.im/blog/minimal-init-process-for-containers/).

Cool hack, huh?

Comment: Very interesting! Found that this is called [YAML merge](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) which I never heard of. The docker-compose usage is documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields). I would say this should be used with care and I'd use the YAML anchors instead (references are in the same link for docker-compose).

Comment: This should be the preferred answer. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: This will result in building several images in case you BUILD them, so not a cool hack. It does not answer the question, which asks directly to reuse image being built by another service

Comment: YAML will unwrap it and you end up with the repeated instructions for each service, so if you typed `build: my_service` that would simply be inserted to every service and the finally this would be 3 images instead of one

Answer (score 8):

If you'd use the following syntax in `docker-compose.yaml` the image will be built once by master, then used by slave:

```
version: '3'

services:
  master:
    build: docker/myservice
    image: master-image:3

  slave:
    image: master-image:3
```

Answer (score 6):

```
services:
  master:
    image: master-image
    pull_policy: never
    build: docker/myservice

  slave:
    image: master-image
    pull_policy: never
```

Without `pull_policy`, `docker compose` works but displays a red error for slave and a warning for master:

⠿ slave Pulling
 ⠿ master Pulling

⠿ slave Error
 ⠿ master Warning

More infos: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9820, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#pull_policy

> pull_policy: never
> Compose implementations SHOULD NOT pull the image from a registry [...]

Other remarks:

- No need for `depends_on` in this context (*"expresses startup and shutdown dependencies between services"*), see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on
- Do not use `version: '3'`, this field is deprecated https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/7d5c7c88676ac240b6b037f868c04b33f738d82a/spec.md#compose-file and also
  it is the equivalent of `'3.0'` instead of using the latest minor version https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3

Comment: Excellent stuff. The `pull_policy: never` was the key for me I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You no longer have to do anything special to reuse an image. The behavior [changed](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7343#issuecomment-863008575) and now `docker compose` only builds once per `Dockerfile`. This works:

```yaml
services:

  foo:
    build: .

  bar:
    build: .
```