# Docker Compose and locally cached images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

My docker compose file defines an image named jetty_base, which creates a simple hardened jetty image.
The dockerfile for this image starts with 
- FROM ubuntu:16.04 AS jetty_base

Later in the compose file I specify another image with the following
dockerfile entry:
FROM jetty_base AS stackone

when I try to run compose up, I get this :

Service 'stackone' failed to build: pull access denied for jetty_base, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

The internet talks about using a forward slash somewhere in the imagename (in the FROM line?)
Does anyone know how to get docker compose to find an image in the local repository?

Comment: I don't think `AS` names the image... have you tried using the `IMAGE` directive to name the image?

Comment: It turns out you have to specify the version number of the image in the compose file... For anyone looking up this question

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how to get docker compose to find an image in the local repository?

You first need to build the image locally from the dockerfile and tag it. Then you can reference that image in the docker-compose.yml

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46036043/4523373) explains this process perfectly.