# Using locally loaded images with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm connected to a machine with no internet connection, so I loaded the Docker image I want to use locally:

```
docker load -i backend.tar
```

It's tagged `backend:latest`.

My `docker-compose.yaml` is configured like so:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
```

But when I'm running `docker-compose up -d backend` I'm getting:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": read tcp <local-ip>:46344-><remote-ip>:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Which means `docker-compose` is trying to reach out to the internet, which he shouldn't.

Is there a way I can force `docker-compose` to use the locally loaded image?

Comment: Does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57644157/13076577 ?

Comment: @araisch sadly it doesn't work

Comment: @Lety that doesn't really say anything

Comment: did you try to list image in order to view if your loaded image is tagged latest?

Answer (score 0):

The kind `docker-compose` community have merged [a fix](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/9376) for this. Coming soon!