# How to use a git url in a Dockerfile as base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have tried things like:

```
FROM https://github.com/someone/somerepo.git#master:/
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think this is possible... I believe you have to build it locally and then use something like: [How can I use a local image as the base image with a dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481225/how-can-i-use-a-local-image-as-the-base-image-with-a-dockerfile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

says

The image can be any valid image – it is especially easy to start by pulling an image from the Public Repositories.

so either your

FROM

references an image available on your host, that you can see with a

`docker images`

or it references an image on the Docker Hub

https://hub.docker.com/

for example

https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/

or

https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

or

https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/

or any other

So it seems, at the moment, you can't use a git repo

Comment: Thanks!

I am still sad about id ;)