# in vscode how do I set the default container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-desktop

Looking at the vscode documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers and section

```
3. After picking the starting point for your container, VS Code will add the dev container configuration files to your project (.devcontainer/devcontainer.json).
```

I can see that the correct container is launched each time, but I do not see a reference to it in the `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "myContainer",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
        "--security-opt",
        "seccomp=unconfined"
    ],
    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
        "lldb.executable": "/usr/bin/lldb",
        // VS Code don't watch files under ./target
        "files.watcherExclude": {
            "**/target/**": true
        }
    },
    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "bungcip.better-toml"
    ],
    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "rustc --version",
    // Comment out connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

then in section https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_create-a-devcontainerjson-file

```
"image": "mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-12",
```

If I am using docker desktop on windows how do format the uri to match the docker desktop container location? for example a `docker ps -a` returns a NAME of `interesting_mccarth`. I do not see how the above string matches to my container I wish to use as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the `devcontainer.json` file references the `Dockerfile` and it is the `Dockerfile` that references the image to use.

```
"build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
}
```

So whether it is a local or remote image that you want to reference inside your `Dockerfile` is really up to you. [Here is an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20501690/1188409) describing how to use a local image inside a `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I tried updating the Dockerfile in vscode to the local image using `FROM myLocalImage-hash`, then `reopen in container` I get asked to rebuild, but this still uses a previous image as the base for the container.  IS there a way to flush the previous entries?

Comment: Yes if you get asked to rebuild it means VSCode detected the changes on the `Dockerfile` you should click on the "Rebuild" button on the notification. Is VSCode stille using the old image event after clicking on the `Rebuild` button ?

Comment: Yes, after some digging it looks like the docker desktop is not a repo vscode can use. I created a local repo and added that as the image, then rebuild and seems to work with the new image. But it does mean vscode has it own cache somewhere. I am trying to find it as it have deleted all the local  images on docker desktop and it still creates on a prev image