# Building a Docker Image using Custom Base Image

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

Working on a Python Project where I need to separate out a child component from a parent component. The child component must use the parent component docker image as a base image and built its image upon it. Both of them uses wheel files for packaging.

How to run the child container by using parent as a dependency ?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Is the "child component" just a Python library (so `COPY` its `.whl` file into the application image and `RUN pip install` it) or a full-blown image with additional native-library dependencies and other setup?  You can build the application image `FROM` anything you want, even a locally-built image; see [How can I use a local image as the base image with a dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481225/how-can-i-use-a-local-image-as-the-base-image-with-a-dockerfile)

Comment: I have a monolithic app which runs inside a Docker Container. Now I want to separate a small module out of it as a child component. The child component needs the parent component to run successfully. Therefore, I separated the Child component which has its own DockerFile and uses the Parent Component base image. Now, I am able to generate the whl files for both parent and child. But when I pip install, its not able to refer the parent component. Hence the child component conatiner, although it starts, doesnt run properly.

Comment: Both are Python based packages. Below is a sample of child docker file. FROM base-image:latest

#dist2 contains parent and child wheel files
COPY src/dist /dist2

RUN ls /dist2/*
ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy
ARG no_proxy


RUN python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade setuptools wheel \
  && python3 -m pip install /dist2/*.whl